# Including vector graphics file (SVG) in a figure generated with the patchwork package

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg, figure, patchwork

For assembling a publication-quality figure using *R*, I think that the widely-used `ggplot2` and `patchwork` packages are suitable frameworks.

I am looking for the best way to include an external vector graphics file in a `ggplot2`/`patchwork` figure.
The file is in SVG format, but converting it to EPS or PostScript or PDF would be no problem.

I tried `grImport2::readPicture('image.svg')`, but it rejects all SVG files I've tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridGraphics)
library(grImport2)

download.file('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrosine#/media/file:L-Tyrosin_-_L-Tyrosine.svg', destfile='image.svg')

img <- grImport2::readPicture('image.svg')
imgGrob <- grImport2::pictureGrob(img)
```

What could be a better solution to include vector graphics in `ggplot2`/`patchwork` figures?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `magick` package to read the SVG image into R, and, to plot the image into a `ggplot2` plot with the `magick::image_ggplot()` function.

https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/reference/image_ggplot.html#arguments

```r
library(magick)
svg_image <- image_read_svg('image.svg')

# Produces a ggplot2 plot with the svg image:
svg_plot <- image_ggplot(svg_image)
```

After that, from what I understand about the `patchwork` package, you can just merge the plots as you would normally do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))

# Merging plots:
plot1 + svg_plot
```